# Alert Dialog not popping up in showbottommodoalsheet function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function `showBottomModalSheet` where the user enters data into a text field. I want to validate the text field to make sure its not empty when the user presses the button and if it is show an alert dialog, but for some reason my alert dialog is not showing up.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    //button to confirm entry
    onPressed: () async {
        //if else check that none of the entries are empty
        if (_exercisenameController.text.isEmpty ||
            _totalweightController.text.isEmpty ||
            _totalrepsController.text.isEmpty) {
            print('Do you even lift');
              
            AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Do you even lift'),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListBody(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                        Text('All Input fields must be filled.'),
                    ],
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                        child: const Text('OK'),
                        onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                    ),
                ],
            );
        } else {
            //Save new journal
            if (id == null) {
                //if the item doesnt exist
                await _addItem();
            }

            if (id != null) {
                //if it exists update it instead
                await _updateItem(id);
            }
        }

        // Clear the text fields
        _exercisenameController.text = '';
        _totalweightController.text = '';
        _totalrepsController.text = '';

        //closing the popup
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
    },
    //the text of the button change depending on if its new or updating an existing
    child: Text(id == null ? 'Create New' : 'Update'),
)
```

I was expecting it to show an alert dialog and when you click okay it goes back to the `showBottommModalSheet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, where instead of just returning the `AlertDialog` you call `showDialog` on it inside your button's `onPressed`:

```dart
showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Do you even lift'),
                    content: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: ListBody(
                        children: const <Widget>[
                            Text('All Input fields must be filled.'),
                        ],
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                        TextButton(
                            child: const Text('OK'),
                            onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                        ),
                    ],
                );
            });
```

*fyi: I don't have an IDE with me, so I'm guessing syntax, but I'm pretty confident there's a function that's called this or very similarly named to this that works and pops up a dialog :D*